# How does one securely update a website?

Tags: php, webserver, file-upload, updates

Imagine that I want to send new files (PHP , SQL , HTML) to a server.
Suppose I use a secure connection. My question is:

***"What is the best way not to end up with an unwanted glitch during the transfer of new files ?"***

An example would be:

"Before updating the website was reasonably secure.
For the new version, I 've updated the system for verifying user identity
: it is now sufficient to write a simple `include($VERIFICATION_FILE_PATH)` where you want to check a user access to content.
Unfortunately, I decided to upload the file `$VERIFICATION_FILE_PATH` last (many PHP files have been modified during this update to use the new system). "

The use of `include` renders server less secure during the upload given that before the file `$VERIFICATION_FILE_PATH` is uploaded they produce *warnings* instead of checking the identity of the user.

I know that the problem can be easily avoided by deciding to upload the file `$VERIFICATION_FILE_PATH` first and then update the others or just replace `include` with `require` (which produces an other glitch...), it's just an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to update a site while it's being used but there are some ways to easily lock the users out of the server while you are updating:

- Put the website on "Maintenance mode" which will redirect the users to another page locking them out of the section being updated.
- Take the entire server offline during the update while you have a caching service on top of it such as Cloudflare which will keep some parts of the website up until the upload is done and you can open it.

Comment: It's absolutely possible to update without any glitch, it just depends on what *effort* and *preparation* you are prepared to put in to do so. For example, you could flip visitors between a copy of the site. In the simplest case, you prepare a copy of the site on the server, update the copy, and flip the document root. Coding site changes to handle the possibility of some files and functions not existing yet is another way, or for a feature to be inactive until enabled. This also enables backing out a change and enables uploading commits that are not yet production ready. *Planning* is key.

Comment: @Nick As I mentioned above he can redirect the users out of the section being updated and "fliping visitors between a copy" still will get a 404 or any other error if they try to visit while a change is taking place

Comment: "still will get a 404 or any other error if they try to visit while a change is taking place" - speaking from experience, not if you do it right. Flipping document root for example is an atomic change and should cause no issue at all. Changes to sub-parts of a site can be similarly handled with alias directives or other techniques. On a larger scale, migrating users to a new server on the fly is similarly possible with no glitch too; at ionCube we've managed complex intra-server updates and migrations seamlessly on multiple occasions. You just need to plan and engineer carefully the change :)

Answer (score 1):

Well normally you shut down the service in question while you update it.

So in your question before uploading your new files to your server you would pick a date, then spread the word that your site will be offline for maintenance at that date, then when that date comes you stop your apache, upload all your files, then restart apache.

So that no-one will be able to access your half-updated website.

Because this is quite complicated (and has some gaps for human error) you will want to have a test server on a trusted LAN where you can try out the whole install process a few times before trying to apply it to a production server.